# Error al instalar slapd y ldap-utils

Tags: linux, debian, redes

estoy intentando instalar slapd y ldap-utils en debian, pero me salta este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tendras un problema con tus DNS... puede ser temporal... prueba otro rato o bien puedes trucar temporalmente tu archivo /etc/hosts y poner esto en la primera línea: `151.101.134.132 deb.debian.org` que es la IP que a mi me resuelve mi DNS ahora (seguramente tienen muchas ips que van rotando, pero en este momento la que se corresponde con mi ubicación es esa) y así tu sistema lo resolverá sin tener que pasar por tu DNS y lo encontrará

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, sigue igual...

Comment: si haces un `ping deb.debian.org` no aparece la IP que has puesto en el `/etc/hosts`?

Comment: He puesto eso en el directorio /etc/hosts y nada

Comment: no es un directorio, es un archivo (espero que no te lo hayas cargado)... estas en linux no?

Comment: Red innacesible

Comment: Estoy en Debian

Comment: eso es que no tienes internet y estas hablando conmigo mediante control mental

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140725/discussion-between-aphans-and-masterguru).